# How to test interactions on delegate called by invoking class?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have the following classes shown below, legacy code. The goal I want to achieve is to ensure that the delegate method processUser is called with the user data passed. Second, I also want to ensure that the passed in Registration object's doRegister is called. My attemot is shown below for the delegate, but the test does not pass as it says, Too few invocations. I am using Groovy spock for testing version 1.2

```java
class Invoker {
    Delegate delegate;

    Invoker(Delegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    void invoke(UserData user) {
        delegate.processUser(user);
    }
}
```

```java
class Delegate {
    private RegistrationService service;

    Delegate (RegistrationService r) {
        this.service = r;
    }

    void processUser(UserData data) {
        service.doRegistration(data);
    }
}
```

```groovy
class DelegateSpec extends Specification {
     Delegate delegate
     RegistrationService registration
     Invoker invoker

     def setup() {
         registration = Mock()
         delegate = new Delegate(registration)
         Invoker invoker = new Invoker(delegate)
     }

     def "Invoker should invoke delegate passed to it"() {
         given:
         UserData u = ....
         when:
         invoker.invoke(u)
         then:
         1* delegate.processUser(u) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be advised to split your code into one block per class, it will be easier to read. Also make sure that when you copy & paste code and then edit it before posting, it actually still makes sense. I fixed a few obvious errors such as different class names for the same thing. It would also be a good idea to always post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including all dependencies, e.g. classes like `RegistrationService` and `UserData`. It would make reproducing your problem and answering the question so much easier. Thank you.

Comment: BreenDeen, I see some kind of inconsistence: the `DelegateSpec` should test only `Delegate` class, but you involved the `Invoker` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me provide a fully consistent set of classes in order to be able to compile the application code:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59366025;

public class UserData {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59366025;

public class RegistrationService {
  public void doRegistration(UserData data) {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59366025;

class Delegate {
  private RegistrationService service;

  Delegate (RegistrationService r) {
    this.service = r;
  }

  void processUser(UserData data) {
    service.doRegistration(data);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59366025;

class Invoker {
  Delegate delegate;

  Invoker(Delegate delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  void invoke(UserData user) {
    delegate.processUser(user);
  }
}
```

Now as for your test, you are making it more complicated than necessary and there is also a logical error:

- If the `Delegate` is not mock or spy, you cannot check interactions like `1 *` on it.
- So just make it a mock, then you also do not need to inject its `RegistrationService` dependency anymore - which is the whole point of creating a mock.

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q59366025

import spock.lang.Specification

class DelegateSpec extends Specification {
  def delegate = Mock(Delegate)
  def invoker = new Invoker(delegate)

  def "Invoker should invoke delegate passed to it"() {
    given:
    def userData = new UserData()
    when:
    invoker.invoke(userData)
    then:
    1 * delegate.processUser(userData)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I really appreciate this.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I really appreciate this.  I get a NullPointerException because the Delegate calls the RegistrationService doRegistration().  i used the Delegate delagate = Spy(constructorArgs: Mock(Registration)) and i don't get an exception. However, then the interaction does not occur.

Comment: Of course with your original code you get `NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method invoke() on null object` because there is a bug in your `setup()` method: You are declaring a local variable instead of assigning to the instance variable: `Invoker invoker = new Invoker(delegate)` Thus, the instance variable `invoker` is null.

Comment: If you change to `invoker = new Invoker(delegate)` you will of course get another error `Too few invocations for: 1 * delegate.processUser(userData)` because the delegate is not a mock or spy and thus interaction checking does not work, as I said before. This also explains why it starts working when you change to `delegate = Spy(constructorArgs: [registration])`. But this is over-engineering. As I said before, you don't need the real object here and spy on it. The mock injected into the spy is also not necessary. My solution is what you should use, otherwise the code is almost obfuscated.

Comment: Besides, your test tests the invoker, not the delegate, and should thus be renamed to `InvokerSpec`.